# Can Consulate Personnel as Individuals, & / or Consulate, be sued under Civil Law of "Receiving" Country by National-Visitor of that Consulate?

Tags: legal, international-law

**Possible Reasons for Suing :**

**1_**
Defamation

**2_**
Terrorism ;
Visitor felt "terrorized" by the behavior, incl. statements committed, through omission & / or by commission, by Personnel of their Consulate

**3_**
other Malfeasance
inter alia

**National-Visitor :**

National of the "Sending" Country
AND 
Visitor to Consulate of Sending Country during which they allegedly were subject to Malfeasance from the Consulate Personnel

Comment: @ Sean Sean Are you an expatriate in the country to which your question refers? Which country(ies) does your question refer to? The question might be better suited to https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So this is about the consulate of country X located in country Y, being visited by a citizen of country Y? Also, are you quoting something here? Then show a link to the original.

Comment: @JanDoggen country X is the sending country, so the question is about a national of country X seeking to sue the consulate of country X under country Y's laws.

Comment: Thank u to the 3 posters above for ur replies.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and supply the additional information that is asked here in the comments? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Being made to feel "terrorized" is not "terrorism".  "Terrorism" is usually  defined as the use of violence for political ends (and in such a way that waging war by nation-states doesn't qualify either).

Answer (score 1):

Consulates and consular personnel enjoy "official acts" immunity.  If the alleged malfeasance was perpetrated in connection with official duties, it would only be possible to pursue in the legal system of the receiving country with the consent of the sending country, that is, if the sending country were to waive immunity.  That would seem extremely unlikely.

If the act were not in connection with official duties, the receiving state could assume jurisdiction, but that would be very difficult to establish given that the malfeasance occurred during a visit to the consular premises.

Comment: Not a sweet answer to for to give hope to one inclined to natural justice ; But,- I think that it is elegant description of the reality. How about the process of suing country X [ sending country ] when citizen of X is 1_ back in country X ? or 2_ in country Y [ receiving country ] ? or 3_ next located in country Z ?

Comment: CLARIFICATION PER JUST PREVIOUS POST ; Here I enquire about starting to sue country X through the respective options of country X when Plaintiff is located 1_ back in country X [ "Sending" country ] ? or 2_ in country Y [ "Receiving" country ] ? or 3_ in some other country Z ?

Comment: @SeanSean if the improper act was an official act then your only hope really is to pursue the matter under the laws of the sending country.  Whether that is possible or realistic depends on the laws of that country.

Comment: @SeanSean The fact you can't use the courts of the receiving country is not a violation of natural justice - you just have to pursue the case in the courts of the sending country.  (If that is not possible, then the sending country may not support natural justice - many don't.)

Comment: All very helpful replies. Yer sharp writing -- even when serving "the wall" that the status quo would serve up -- is very useful for me in my preparations to bring 'em to justice. AT THIS JUNCTURE,- I WOULD APPRECIATE GREATEST LIST OF   P-R-E-C-E-D-E-N-T-S   WHERE CITIZENS OF CONSULATE'S SENDING COUNTRY WERE SUCCESSFUL IN SUING CONSULATE CIVIL SERVANTS FOR WRONG DOING IN PUBLIC OFFICE [ MALFEASANCE ]. This whole pursuit will be for the greater good of all citizens & subjects of countries worldwide. Thanking yee all in advance, Sean Sean.